# Javascript: Get the value of attributes of "FORM " which is created in .html to external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the small html code where javascript/jquery is inserted inside the  tag. This approach works fine.

Now I want to divide this single file into ".html" & ".js". Where I want to separate all javascript/jquery coding part into ".js"

But the problem here I faced is that I am not able to read the values(in ".js") of any field which I have created in ".html"

**Example**

test.html:

```
<form name="attachlaunchform" id="attachlaunchform" class="form">
<input type="text" name="serial_number" id="serial_number" maxlength="16">
```

test.js:

```
serial_num=document.attachlaunchform.serial_number.value
```

I have included source of my external js file also.

But if I put all these in single file in test.html, it works.My query is how can I get the text box or any other value in .js?

Comment: You want a separation of html and js, right?

Comment: Forgot to mention I have even included the .js file in .html

Comment: Yes I want to separate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say-

Assuming you have number of events in your html file like-

```
$('element1').click(function(){});

$('element2').keydown(function(){});

$('element1').bind('click mouseover',function(){});

function initFunction(){
      //something
   }

$(document).ready(function(){
 initFunction();
});
```

You can separate it by making an external `.js` file(you already trying this)

Standardize this file as an extension not just an external source.

Now separating all above functions in `.js` file-

```
(function($){

 function events(){

    $('element1').click(function(){});

    $('element2').keydown(function(){});

    $('element1').bind('click mouseover',function(){});

   }

 function  initFunction(){
          //something
       }

   $(window).on('load',function(){
      events();
      initFunction();
   });

});
```

and then simply use this file in your html file.